# No sound after new installation of Windows 11

Tags: audio, windows-11

Yesterday I've done a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro on a Lenovo Thinkpad, then upgraded to Windows 11, did all the updates. Today I found out that there is no sound. In the Windows taskbar I can turn the sound on and off, move the volume bar to 100%.

The keyboard has 3 sound keys: volume up, volume down and on/off. The on/off key has a light that is on when the sound is off. This light is on all the time. When I press the button, I see the taskbar sound icon go on and off, so Windows does recognize it. This laptop has had sound before. The microphone works. I've tried different programs.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: What is your audio device and what driver have you installed? What exact model is the Thinkpad?

Comment: Have you tested headphones and/or external speakers?

Comment: reinstall the sound driver.